# Get the minimum value of fields that are not empty

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to get the Minimum time value of a field in report. The thing is the field has null values and the `Minimum` function returns the null/empty value. The `Maximum` function grabs the last time value. I have tried to suppress the details section that this field is in, but alas it returns the same result.

Example:

```
10:00:01   |            |
           |  10:00:03  |
           |  10:01:00  |
           |            |
           |  10:03:12  |
```

So in column two here I am trying to retrieve `10:00:03`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Great workaround, thought I would share...

Check if field is empty, if so then set it to `23:59:59` then the `Minimum` function works as expected.